# DirectX11 DirectXTK need a CSO file for testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx, directx-11

I am piecing together information on how to import models following a bunch of different tutorials, because there isn't a resource that explains how to do this in a simple way.

So far I can import and display my model, but it's shown in the Gouraud shader  if I use DirectX::BasicEffect

This makes my mechanical models appear very badly shaded, because they were exported from Solidworks.

I want to try switching to DirectX::DGSLEffect , but I need to load a shader, and I don't have any shaders to test.

Can anyone point me to where I can find a pre-compiled *.cso shader?

I need one that can preferably do flat shading, but I can settle for any, just to test that my application is working right.

I know that I need to compile a shader myself from .hlsl files, but this is too many steps and I just need something that works right now before I can continue further,

Thank you,
-D

I want to point out that I am not making a video game, but a mechanical visualization tool, and I do not need to know how to write shaders or do any advanced features of DirectX at this time. Please do not recommend reading books as that would be counter-productive to the amount of time I can work on this project. I would like to learn more in the future, but not for this application. Thanks,

EDIT:

It looks like I can compile with the following line, but now I cant find any HLSL files.

```
ID3DBlob* PS_Buffer;
D3DCompileFromFile(L"PixelSHader.hlsl", 0, 0, "main", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0);
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: DirectX 11 is a low level graphics API to get a lot of juice from hardware. If you don't want to deal with shaders, why use DirectX at all? There are many simpler solutions for CAD and scientific visualization.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I am NOT looking for a book, just a snippet of HLSL code to get started

Answer (score 0):

`CSO` files are complied HLSL shaders. Visual Studio can generate them from `HLSL` files, and the DGSL pipeline can create pixel shaders using a visual language.

> The *DirectX Tool Kit* BasicEffect system is quite flexible, so you can override in code the parameters or provide your own material information. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Effects) for more information.

If you want to use the Visual Studio content pipeline, you should look at [Working with 3-D Assets for Games and Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315737.aspx) for the details. Visual Studio converts WaveFront `obj` or Autodesk `fbx` files and can include DGSL materials as part of that pipeline. The *DirectX Tool Kit* `DGSLEffect` provides a built-in vertex shader that will work with the DGSL shader designer output.

If you'd like an example of using the `DGSLEffect` pipeline, look at the tutorial [Creating custom shaders with DGSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Creating-custom-shaders-with-DGSL).